# C++ array compile

Tags: c++, xcode

I keep getting 3 compiling errors that say "Function definition is not allowed". I am not sure on how to fix it. I keep getting it after the int main, and after the void functions. Please help!

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int populateIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr, int arraySize);
void displayIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr, int arraySize);
int findMaximumInteger(int *arrayPtr, int arraySize);

int populateIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
{
   for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
   {
       cout<<"Enter value for array element "<<i<<":";
       cin>>arrayPtr[i];//reading values
   }

void displayIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
{
   for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
   cout<<&arrayPtr[i]<<": arrayPtr["<<i<<"] = "<<setw(15)<<arrayPtr[i]<<endl;
}

void findMaximumInteger(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
{
   int maximum = arrayPtr[0];
   for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
   {
       if(maximum<arrayPtr[i])max=arrayPtr[i];
   }
   cout<<"Maximum integer in array is: "<<max<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   //reading array size
   cout<<"Enter desired array size:";
   cin>>n;
   int *a = new int[n];

   cout<<"arrayPtr = "<<a<<endl;
   populateIntegerArray(a,n);
   displayIntegerArray(a,n);
   findMaximumInteger(a,n);
   cout<<"DELETING array at arrayPtr = "<<a<<endl;
   delete a;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing `}` at the end of the body of `populateIntegerArray()`.   The compiler therefore interprets that you are trying to implement subsequent functions within the body of `populateIntegerArray()` which is not allowed in C++.   Add a properly placed `}`.

Comment: thanks I fixed it but I still have 2 errors @Peter

Comment: Well, fix them.   I've addressed the problem you asked about, and correcting that  will expose other problems.    It's your job to get the code working.  A key skill you need to develop is interpreting the diagnostics from the compiler, in order to fix the problems.

Comment: Only 1 of the errors was fixed because I was missing a bracket and I caught it myself. It did not cause any additional problems aside from the ones that it originally had so I posted here for a reason because I am stuck. If I was able to do it on my own, I wouldn't have made the post. @Peter

Answer (score 2):

First, you are missing the last `}` after the definition of `populateIntegerArray` and before the `displayIntegerArray`:

```
int populateIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
{
   for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
   {
       cout<<"Enter value for array element "<<i<<":";
       cin>>arrayPtr[i];//reading values
   }

void displayIntegerArray(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
```

Then, you have the following prototype:

```
int findMaximumInteger(int *arrayPtr, int arraySize);
```

But you define the actual function as returning `void` (it should be `int` instead):

```
void findMaximumInteger(int *arrayPtr,int arraySize)
{
```

Then, in your `findMaximumInteger` function, you are not defining the `max` variable anywhere.

Functions `populateIntegerArray` and `findMaximumInteger` are declared as returning `int`, but actually do not return a value. You should either return an integer, or (if you intend to just output the result to console without returning a value from a function) change the functions' prototypes to returning `void` (not `int`).

Comment: I still have two errors: after the findMaxiumumInteger it says function definition is not allowed and at the end of the code it says expected } but there's one there already @heap underrun